# Prisma version error when running with new relic

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma, newrelic

I'm learning how to use new relic, but when trying to start an application with prisma, the following error returns:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'version')
    at initialize (D:\pessoal\newrelic\node_modules\newrelic\lib\instrumentation\@prisma\client.js:157:52)
    at _firstPartyInstrumentation (D:\pessoal\newrelic\node_modules\newrelic\lib\shimmer.js:575:29)
    at D:\pessoal\newrelic\node_modules\newrelic\lib\shimmer.js:538:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at instrumentPostLoad (D:\pessoal\newrelic\node_modules\newrelic\lib\shimmer.js:497:20)
    at _postLoad (D:\pessoal\newrelic\node_modules\newrelic\lib\shimmer.js:597:12)
    at onHook (D:\pessoal\newrelic\node_modules\newrelic\lib\shimmer.js:356:14)
    at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (D:\pessoal\newrelic\node_modules\require-in-the-middle\index.js:262:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\pessoal\newrelic\server.ts:3:1)
```

This is my `server.ts` file:

```
require('newrelic')

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import express from 'express';

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('teste')
})

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
    const users = await prisma.user.findMany()
    res.json(users) 
})

prisma.$connect()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('conectado')
        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('rodando na 3000 ')
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

If I remove the import from Prisma Client, it works normally.

My `package.json:`

```
{

 "name": "newrelic",

 "version": "1.0.0",

 "description": "",

 "main": "index.js",

 "scripts": {

  "start": "ts-node-dev -r newrelic -r dotenv/config server.ts"

 },

 "keywords": [],

 "author": "",

 "license": "ISC",

 "dependencies": {

  "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1",

  "@types/newrelic": "^9.14.0",

  "dotenv": "^16.3.1",

  "express": "^4.18.2",

  "newrelic": "^11.1.0"

 },

 "devDependencies": {

  "prisma": "^5.3.1",

  "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0"

 }

}
```

Inside the file `node_modules\newrelic\lib\instrumentation\@prisma\client.js`, if I change the following line, it works again:

```
module.exports = async function initialize(_agent, prisma, _moduleName, shim) {
  // const pkgVersion = shim.require('./package.json').version
  const pkgVersion = "5.3.1"
  if (semver.lt(pkgVersion, '4.0.0')) {
    logger.warn(
      'Skipping instrumentation of @prisma/client.  Minimum supported version of library is 4.0.0, actual version %s',
      pkgVersion
    )
    return
  }
...
```